# How would one change this Functional React Component to one that uses Recompose?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, recompose

I have the following functional component that I am interested in hearing how one may go about changing this to a `branch` enhanced component as opposed to the `if` statement.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Button, Icon, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { setPropTypes, branch } from 'recompose'

const LoginOrMiniProfile = ({presence}) => {
    if (presence.account) {
        return (
            <Link to='/profile'>
                <Label>
                    <Icon name='user circle outline' />
                    {presence.account.firstName}
                </Label>
            </Link>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button primary className={`login ${presence.loading && 'loading'}`}>Signup</Button>
                <Button className={`login ${presence.loading && 'loading'}`}>Login</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default setPropTypes({
    prensence: PropTypes.object.isRequired
})(LoginOrMiniProfile)
```

And for bonus points, how would one use Recompose to access and change `presence` in a Redux store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example to achieve what you want. You can (and should) do some refactor, like defining the inline functional components in other places.

```
compose(
  connect(
    ({ presence }) => ({ presence }), // get presence from the redux store via `connect`
    {
      updatePresence: updatePresenceActionCreator // inject dispatch(updatePresence) to props
    }
  ),
  setPropTypes({
    prensence: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    updatePresence: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }),
  branch(
    ({ presence }) => presence.account,
    renderComponent(({ presence }) =>
      <Link to="/profile">
        <Label>
          <Icon name="user circle outline" />
          {presence.account.firstName}
        </Label>
      </Link>
    )
  )
)(({ 
  presence,
  updatePresence // you can update your presence by invoking this function
}) =>
  <div>
    <Button primary className={`login ${presence.loading && "loading"}`}>
      Signup
    </Button>
    <Button className={`login ${presence.loading && "loading"}`}>Login</Button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I didn't mention it, but presence is set up by the parent component. I think the issue I had was understanding using `branch` in this way means "render the base component unless this is set, otherwise render the passed in component." I was expecting an if-then-else kind of semantic explicitness with `branch`. I think I have a better understanding of recompose now. Thanks!

Comment: @Dallas I'm glad that my answer is helping :)